# Syncing iPhone 5c with Banshee

Tags: music, banshee, iphone

Hi everyone I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Banshee 2.6.2, and the phone I'm attempting to sync is an iPhone 5c, iOS 9.2. I recently downloaded Banshee so that I can sync my phone, however it does not appear in the devices list. (It's definitely supported; I checked in extensions) It is recognized by my computer though, like with Shotwell asking me about photos and such. Any help? If it's relevant, I couldn't import any media to Banshee without disabling the Podcasts extension, as it would freeze. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think banshee supports iphone sync. I don't think anything can sync music to an iphone other than itunes.

The manual here: https://help.gnome.org/users/banshee/2.6/sync.html.en says "with the notable exception of..." meaning it cannot sync iphone or ipods.

Comment: Huh, really? According to Banshee's FAQ it says the feature has been available since 1.7.5, and in the extensions there is one for Apple support...